# How to convert the mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in a DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x

My DataFrame looks as follow:

```
           VIX Open  VIX High  VIX Low  VIX Close
Date                                            
1/2/2004     17.96     18.68    17.54      18.22
1/5/2004     18.45     18.49    17.44      17.49
1/6/2004     17.66     17.67    16.19      16.73
1/7/2004     16.72     16.75    15.50      15.50
1/8/2004     15.42     15.68    15.32      15.61
```

The above printing is from print(df_old). What I want is the Date format conver to YYYY-MM-DD, i.g. df_new = function(df_old) and it should look as follow:

```
print(df_new) =
              VIX Open  VIX High  VIX Low  VIX Close
Date                                            
2004-01-02     17.96     18.68    17.54      18.22
2004-01-05     18.45     18.49    17.44      17.49
2004-01-06     17.66     17.67    16.19      16.73
2004-01-07     16.72     16.75    15.50      15.50
2004-01-08     15.42     15.68    15.32      15.61
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `strf, strp` and parse the date.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.strptime('1/2/2004','%d/%m/%Y'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

> -old date: 1/2/2004(DD/MM/YYYY)
>
> -new date: 2004-02-01(YYYY-MM-DD)

make a list of dates and pass the variable.

Comment: I know one can do that. But what I want is convert it in the DataFrame. What I posted before is from print(df).  Assumed my DataFrame is called df. How to do?